# Array references by name

Tags: java

why name of array "list" first printed as reference and second code printed content of it.

```
int[] list = new int[5];
list[0] = 1;
list[1] = 2;
System.out.println(list);
```

It prints the reference `[I@4dd8dc3` and i know that i should use for loop to iterate over elements.

**But** **why there is in other code gives me the content not the address? Is that specific for generics?**

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
System.out.println(list);
```

that prints `[1, 2]`

Comment: You are mixing *lists* with *arrays*. `ArrayList` redefines `toString()` to print list contents, whereas an array object does not.

Comment: *"Is that specific for generics?"* - Nope.  Generics have nothing to do with it.  It is all about how (or where) the `toString()` method is implemented for the object you are printing.